# Exception handling in angular using spring as backend

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, exception

I am using a global error handler which simply uses console.log for now. When i get a exception from my spring controller like below i would like to log it on the console. but when i log the error i get the below message

Chrome Console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Eclipse Console

```
Sep 26, 2017 4:16:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [springmvc-dispatcher] in context with path  threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.ektorp.UpdateConflictException: document update conflict: id: unknown rev: unknown] with root cause
org.ektorp.UpdateConflictException: document update conflict: id: unknown rev: unknown
```

I would like to show the real exception to user, but all i get is internal server error.

Error Handler

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalMessageService } from 'app/service/messageService';
import { EGlobalModal } from 'app/model/eGlobalModal';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler{

    constructor(private _msgService:GlobalMessageService){

    }

    handleError(error){

        console.log("error",error);


    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using the http module to query the server

Comment: Yes @IzzoObella

Comment: i've not really used spring boot but for nodejs i try and catch and in catch exception i return the exception to the server don't know if its the same thing i spring boot, do you have an error handling method

Comment: no i am using the default spring methods. Maybe i should manupilate the response in the spring ? @IzzoObella